# Error when adding rows to to tbody of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code.
  My question has to do with the append function inside of the for loop. The string passed to the function isn't parsing correctly, and I am getting an error. How do I correct this?

Thanks!

```
function getDetailPopUp(detailBy)
{
   $.getJSON('/index.cfm/reports/productivity/getDetailPopUp', {
    rollUpType:'byUser'

}, function(result){

for (i=1;i<=result.length;i++)
    {
        $('#detailTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+ result[i][0]+ '</td><td>'+                       
        result[i]][1]+ '</td><td>'+ result[i][2]+'</td><td>'+result[i][3]+ '</td>                    
         <td>'+result[i][4]+'</td><td>'+result[i][5]+'</td><td>'+result[i][6]+'
          </td><td>'+result[i][7]+'</td><td>'+result[i][8]+ '</td></tr>');
}   

$("#details").fadeIn();

});

}       




<div id="details" width=80%>

<table id="detailTable"  style="height:100px; overflow:scroll">

            <thead>
                <th>Calls</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
                <th>Col5</th>
                <th>Col6</th>
                <th>Col7</th>
                <th>Col8</th>
                <th>Col9</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>         
            </tbody>      
</table>    
</div>
```

Comment: `result[i]][1]` should be `result[i][1]` with out the extra `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The string passed to the function
>   isn't parsing correctly, and I am
>   getting an error.

You can't have line breaks inside strings:

```
$('#detailTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+ result[i][0]+ '</td><td>'+                       
     result[i]][1]+ '</td><td>'+ result[i][2]+'</td><td>'+result[i][3]+ '</td>                    
-->  <td>'+result[i][4]+'</td><td>'+result[i][5]+'</td><td>'+result[i][6]+'
     </td><td>'+result[i][7]+'</td><td>'+result[i][8]+ '</td></tr>');
```

And you have `result[i]][1]`, with an extra `]`.

This will work:

```
$('#detailTable > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr><td>'+ result[i][0]+ '</td><td>'+                       
    result[i][1]+ '</td><td>'+ result[i][2]+'</td><td>'+result[i][3]+ '</td>'+                   
    '<td>'+result[i][4]+'</td><td>'+result[i][5]+'</td><td>'+result[i][6]+
    '</td><td>'+result[i][7]+'</td><td>'+result[i][8]+ '</td></tr>'
);
```

Although for readability, you'd be better with:

```
$('#detailTable > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][0] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][1] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][2] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][3] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][4] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][5] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][6] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][7] + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + result[i][8] + '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I removed the bracket and reformatted the string. Now I am getting "result[i] is undefined" error. I am able to do alert(result[i][0]); inside the for loop and it works. Why doesn't it knw that "i" is a variable, not a literal value.

Comment: Ahh, I realized i had undefined values in my result array. You syntax is working for me now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('#detailTable > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr><td>'+ result[i][0]+ '</td><td>'+                       
    result[i][1]+ '</td><td>'+ result[i][2]+'</td><td>'+result[i][3]+ '</td>'+                   
    '<td>'+result[i][4]+'</td><td>'+result[i][5]+'</td><td>'+result[i][6]+
    '</td><td>'+result[i][7]+'</td><td>'+result[i][8]+ '</td></tr>'
);
```

I would suggest you to use templates to build this type of markup. There are many libraries available like Underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe thirtydot has spotted your problems.  A line break inside a string as well as an extra ']'.

I would also suggest using javascript's 'join' function on your array, rather than writing all that out explicitly.

```
$('#detailTable > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + result[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td>'
    '</tr>'
);
```

Comment: Yup. I somehow didn't think of that. Shame on me.